# Bellman principle and approximability

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, approximation-algorithms, approximation-hardness, dynamic-programming

Does anybody know if a combinatorial optimzation problem that enjoys the Bellman's optimality principle can in automatic way be approximated?

Comment: [Bellman's optimality principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_equation#Bellman.27s_Principle_of_Optimality)

Answer (score 5):

One (old but useful) reference along these lines is Woeginger's 1998 paper on the connection between DPs and approximability:

> [When Does a Dynamic Programming Formulation Guarantee the Existence
>   of a Fully Polynomial Time Approximation Scheme (FPTAS)?](http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/ijoc.12.1.57.11901)